# Transactions in key/value store

Tags: database, key-value-store

Which from the well-known key/value stores has also the transaction support? We just need to interlace operations in transactions and rollback from time to time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I'd recommend using REDIS. I've used it for a number of different applications and it's solid, fast and has a great community around it.

And it fully supports transactions: here's information on [REDIS Transactional Support](http://redis.io/topics/transactions)

Answer (score 5):

In case anyone stumbles on this in the future.

[FoundationDB](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/FoundationDB) is fully ACID

Looks like foundation db has gone and this isn't relevant anymore link has been updated to Wikipedia

Comment: Link is broken!

Comment: FoundationDB has been revived -- https://apple.github.io/foundationdb .

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very knowledgable about KV databases, but [Berkeley DB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_DB) springs to mind.